# Can I control where CKEditor finds plugins to load?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I'm writing a CKEditor plugin specific to my Web app. Until now, I've successfully kept my own files outside of the CKEditor code structure, but the only documentation I can find about the plugin creation process (being a [user-made tutorial](http://www.voofie.com/content/2/ckeditor-plugin-development/), no less) says to just shoehorn my plugin code into `ckeditor/_source/plugins`.

Is this really the only way to go? Am I stuck with commingling my code with CKEditor release code, or is there a way to tell it where to load plugins from? A PLUGINPATH setting, if you will?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looking at the tutorial you posted, I see that the section called Plugin Configuration uses `CKEDITOR.plugins.add` to load the plugin resources. Have you tried using `CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal` instead? [The API documentation for it can be found here.](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.resourceManager.html#addExternal)

Comment: Aha! Yes, that's what I'm after. I take it I need to run that function from a customConfig script?

Comment: It worked; I added `CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal('foo', '/media/js/plugins/ckeditor/foo/')` to my custom config.js, outside of the `CKEDITOR.editorConfig = {...}` block. Thanks!

Comment: Note that `addExternal` doesn't actually load the plugin; it just tells CKEditor where to find it. After calling it you still need to tell it to load by adding it to the `CKEDITOR.extraPlugins` property.

Answer (score 0):

You want to load the uncompressed, unpacked plugins to load for debugging purposes right?

Just do this. Refer `ckeditor_source.js` instead of <strike>`ckeditor.js`</strike>. That way your created plugin inside the `ckeditor/_source/plugin`s will run.

Read [Minimum Setup for CKEditor](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Minimum_Setup) with a microscope :)
There is a line like this here

> _source — this directory contains CKEditor source code. It is needed
>   only if you intend to use the
>   ckeditor_source.js script and load
>   CKEditor from source files.

Too little documentation for a wonderful editor!

Update:

And inside the wonderful tutorial link you have provided, George Wu has mentioned that in the first paragraph also.

> During development, you will want to
>   execute from source code by using
>   ckeditor_source.js instead of
>   ckeditor.js.
>
> Now, create
>   ckeditor_source\plugins\footnote
>   folder and plugin.js under that
>   folder.

BTW, I found [`Tutorial create external plugin for CKEDITOR`](http://cksource.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=18876&start=0) helpful too.

Comment: I know, but that's the problem — as I said, I don't *want* to put my plugin source inside the `ckeditor/` structure.